# Munin: Graphs for Processes priority are empty

Tags: munin

I have a new Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, server version without GUI, running as a virtual server in a remote server farm), and I installed munin on it (munin and munin-node). I did not change anything from the standard installation, so at the moment I use the 30 plugins that are part of the standard installation. 28 of them worked fine from the beginning.

The plugin "HTTP load time of a page" showed an empty graph, but I found out that the package `time` was missing. I installed it with

```
apt install time
```

and restarted munin-node. So now this plugin is fixed.

But there still is a problem with »processes priority« (plugin »proc_pri«). The graphs of this plugin (by day, by week, ...) are all empty, and I have now idea where I could start to search for the reason of this problem.

Please can you give me some hints what I could do to fix this problem? Or what I could do to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `ps -eo stat` command. Munin plugin `proc_pri` is the simple shell script that process output of `ps` and may fail after output format changing.
UPD: It simply count lines with symbols ">", "N" and "L" in the `ps  -eo stat` command output. Therefore if this command dont show full list of processes or use non-BSD output format, plugin will not count processes correctly.

Comment: `ps -eo stat` displays only one column (only STAT, no procname, no anything). So I did `ps -eo "user pid comm stat"`. But there is no process named "proc_pri" (also no process with similar name). The only relevant process is "munin-node", it's stat is "Ss". How does this help to solve my problem?